# Is there a way to debug assembly load problems in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core

When I run a WinForms executable in .NET Core, the EXE doesn't start without any message. Running it using

```
dotnet test.dll
```

leads to this error message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ALibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
File name: 'ALibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'
```

The library lays directly side-by-side with the EXE.

Is there any option to debug such a case or get a better error message? The fusion log in .NET 4 provided much more information and could be used to find the real cause of such a problem. Is there anything similar in .NET Core?

Comment: Have you tried to put the dll in the folder where the project.csproj lays?

Comment: It's not only one DLL. And how should this help to get a better error message?

Comment: I had a similar problem and mine was fixed by copying at the time.

Comment: I ran into this feature some time ago as a bug. After moving to the new project format it referenced the wrong assembly as it lay below the project dir :)